# How do you know that rows are independent and what are the 120 terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with the question below, help me out;

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hints rather than answers:

(a) how 'big' is the subspace spanned by the last three rows?  Can three vectors be linearly independent in that subspace?

(b) Are you familiar with the pigeonhole principle?  This is (at some level) a very simple application of that, and related to the answer to (a): each of the 120 terms in the determinant corresponds to one of the $5!$ permutations of the numbers $(1,2,3,4,5)$, where for instance the permutation $(3,2,1,5,4)$ indicates that we take the product of the 3rd element of the 1st row, the 2nd element of the 2nd row, the 1st element of the 3rd row, the 5th element of the 4th row, and the 4th element of the 5th row.  Each such permutation must take some element from the third row, some element from the fourth row, and some element from the fifth row, and it can never take the same element.  Can you see why this implies that one of the elements it takes must be zero?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If a matrix $M$ is written in square blocks, like $$M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ \mathbf{0} & D \end{pmatrix}$$
then: $$\det M = \det A ~\det D$$

Answer (score 0):

(a) row 1 = row 2, so they are not linearly independent.

(b) Any term in the determinant expansion will have a $0$ term, as for any permutation you have to pick at least one zero from the first 3 columns.

Comment: It's poorly-written, but I think the intention is that not all the $x$ represent the _same_ number, so you can't say that row 1 = row 2.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Oops, you are probably right. Thanks for pointing that out. Will delete in a few.

Comment: The rows are dependent. This is mentioned in (a)